# Jenkins pipeline - shutdown GCP instance - iterate issue

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline, gcloud, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to run Jenkins pipeline that stops all instances inside GCP project. The problem is that the instances are not located in the same zone, therefore I want to create the zone value as an array and I'm trying to loop it with no Success - The error I'm getting is **script.sh: 4: Bad substitution**

```
> pipeline {   agent { label 'Agent' }    
  environment {
    CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT='test-project '
    ZONES="us-central1-a,us-central1-b,us-central1-c,us-central1-f"   }   
  stages {
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'gcloud-jenkins-sa', variable: 'GCLOUD_CREDS')]) {
          script {
            sh '''
              gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="$GCLOUD_CREDS"
              for ZONE in "${ZONES[@]}"; do
                INSTANCES=$(gcloud compute instances list --format="value(name)" --zone="$ZONE")
                for INSTANCE in $INSTANCES; do
                  echo "instance name to be powered off: $INSTANCE"
                  gcloud compute instances stop $INSTANCE --zone=$ZONE
                done
              done
            '''
          }
        }
      }
    }   
 }
```

}

BTW - This one works but without setting zone as array

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'Agent' }
   environment {
    CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT='blal'
    ZONE='us-central1-c'
  }
  stages {
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'jenkinscreds', variable: 'GCLOUD_CREDS')]) {
          sh '''
            gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="$GCLOUD_CREDS"
            INSTANCES=$(gcloud compute instances list --format="value(name)")
            for INSTANCE in $INSTANCES; do
                 echo "instance name to be powered off: $INSTANCE"
                 gcloud compute instances stop $INSTANCE --zone $ZONE --quiet
            done
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```